Searching for the nearest space or bracket - can it be more general?
I grep Common Lisp code base and extract usage of the symbol I am interested in analysing. Then I copy it to scratchpad to clean up the grep. I know of sorting lines and removing duplicates, but before I get to that point I need to clean up the results a bit. Searching backwards is easy but when searching forward I came up with the following code, that searches for the following space or closing bracket. Can it me made more general? How can I improve it?
(defun search-nearest-space-or-bracket ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((s0-point (point)))
    (let ((s1-point (search-forward " " nil t)))
      (goto-char s0-point)
      (let ((s2-point (search-forward ")" nil t)))
        (goto-char (cond
                    ((and (null s1-point) (null s2-point))
                     s0-point)
                    ((and (null s1-point) (not (null s2-point)))
                     s2-point)
                    ((and (not (null s1-point)) (null s2-point))
                     s1-point)
                    (t (min s1-point s2-point))))))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-z V") 'search-nearest-space-or-bracket)

Another approach with more possible characters
Refined regex version
(require 'cl-lib)
(defun search-nearest-space-or-bracket ()
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (1- (car (cl-sort (cl-remove-if #'null
                                             (list (re-search-forward " \\|)\\|\n" nil t)
                                                   (1+ (point))))
                               #'<=)))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-z V") 'search-nearest-space-or-bracket)


Be more specific about what you're looking for. "More general" and "improve it" are too vague.

regular expression instead of 2 hardcoded cases is an example of more general improvement

Yes. Use (re-search-forward " \\|(" nil t) instead.

(re-search-forward "[ )]" nil t)  <== that worked for me
